# Efficient algorithm for getting number of partitions of integer with distinct parts (Partition function Q)

Tags: python, algorithm, partitioning

I need to create function which will take one argument `int` and output `int` which represents the number of distinct parts of input integer's partition. Namely,

```
input:3 -> output: 1 -> {1, 2}
input:6 -> output: 3 -> {1, 2, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 5}
...
```

Since I am looking only for distinct parts, something like this is not allowed:

`4 -> {1, 1, 1, 1} or {1, 1, 2}`

So far I have managed to come up with some algorithms which would find every possible combination, but they are pretty slow and effective only until `n=100` or so.
And since I only need **number** of combinations not the combinations themselves *Partition Function Q* should solve the problem.
Does anybody know how to implement this efficiently?

More information about the problem: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000009), [Partition Function Q](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html)

EDIT:

To avoid any confusion, the `DarrylG` answer also includes the trivial (single) partition, but this does not affect the quality of it in any way.

EDIT 2:
The `jodag` (accepted answer) does not include trivial partition.

Comment: The link you provided gives a pretty clear set of function definitions for a memo-ized function to compute Q(n). Have you tried implementing that? Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't achieved much, because I can't handle recursion properly especially `s(n)` part. So if you could give me a hint I will try to come up with something. Thanks

Comment: @kaktus_car--in my answer I implemented the approach in your  Wolfram link and a simpler approach.  The Wolfram was orders of magnitude faster than using a simple recurrence relation even with Memoization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a straightforward and efficient way to solve this is to explicitly compute the coefficient of the generating function from the [Wolfram PartitionsQ link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) in the original post.

This is a pretty illustrative example of how to construct generating functions and how they can be used to count solutions. To start, we recognize that the problem may be posed as follows:

```
Let m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_{n-1} = n where m_j = 0 or m_j = j for all j.

Q(n) is the number of solutions of the equation.
```

We can find `Q(n)` by constructing the following polynomial (i.e. the generating function)

```
(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^3)...(1 + x^(n-1))
```

The number of solutions is the number of ways the terms combine to make `x^n`, i.e. the coefficient of `x^n` after expanding the polynomial. Therefore, we can solve the problem by simply performing the polynomial multiplication.

```py
def Q(n):
    # Represent polynomial as a list of coefficients from x^0 to x^n.
    # G_0 = 1
    G = [int(g_pow == 0) for g_pow in range(n + 1)]
    for k in range(1, n):
        # G_k = G_{k-1} * (1 + x^k)
        # This is equivalent to adding G shifted to the right by k to G
        # Ignore powers greater than n since we don't need them.
        G = [G[g_pow] if g_pow - k < 0 else G[g_pow] + G[g_pow - k] for g_pow in range(n + 1)]
    return G[n]
```

Timing (average of 1000 iterations)

```py
import time
print("n    Time (sec)")
for n in [10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000]:
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        Q(n)
    elapsed = time.time() - t0
    print('%-5d%.08f'%(n, elapsed / 1000))
```

```
n    Time (sec)
10   0.00001000
50   0.00017500
100  0.00062900
200  0.00231200
300  0.00561900
500  0.01681900
1000 0.06701700
```

Comment: First, sorry for the late response and thank you for your answer. Now, this is definitely a great approach. It is faster than the currently accepted one and your solution is not recursive so it won't raise the `Recursion error` which happens with the mentioned solution when `n >= 250` . As far as I see I should accept your answer, of course if there are arguments against, I am more than open for discussion.

Comment: I believe this is the best solution of all, can you give clues on how was this derived?

Comment: I can see now this is from the recursive realtionship here: https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/p/p121.htm

it finds the rest of coefficients, knowing only the first coefficient which is 1

Comment: @IlyaAhmed The explanation is in the answer. If there's a particular part of the setup or solution that you don't understand then please elaborate. This is a basic generating function problem. The generating function is a polynomial, the coefficient of x^(n-1) is the number of solutions. We just perform the polynomial multiplication for each term to get the coefficients of the polynomial, truncating to only terms with order less than x^n.

Answer (score 7):

**Tested two algorithms**

1. Simple recurrence relation
2. WolframMathword algorithm (based upon Georgiadis, Kediaya, Sloane)

> Both implemented with Memoization using LRUCache.
>
> Results: WolframeMathword approach orders of magnitude faster.

**1. Simple recurrence relation (with Memoization)**

[Reference](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71941/strict-partitions-of-a-positive-integer)

*Code*

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def p(n, d=0):
  if n:
    return sum(p(n-k, n-2*k+1) for k in range(1, n-d+1))
  else:
    return 1
```

*Performance*

```
n    Time (sec)
10   time elapsed: 0.0020
50   time elapsed: 0.5530
100  time elapsed: 8.7430
200  time elapsed: 168.5830
```

**2. WolframMathword algorithm**

(based upon Georgiadis, Kediaya, Sloane)

[Reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html)

**Code**

```
# Implementation of q recurrence
# https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html
class PartitionQ():
  def __init__(self, MAXN):
    self.MAXN = MAXN
    self.j_seq = self.calc_j_seq(MAXN)

  @lru_cache
  def q(self, n):
    " Q strict partition function "
    assert n < self.MAXN
    if n == 0:
      return 1

    sqrt_n = int(sqrt(n)) + 1
    temp = sum(((-1)**(k+1))*self.q(n-k*k) for k in range(1, sqrt_n))

    return 2*temp + self.s(n)

  def s(self, n):
    if n in self.j_seq:
      return (-1)**self.j_seq[n]
    else:
      return 0

  def calc_j_seq(self, MAX_N):
    """ Used to determine if n of form j*(3*j (+/-) 1) / 2 
        by creating a dictionary of n, j value pairs "
    result = {}
    j = 0
    valn = -1
    while valn <= MAX_N:
      jj = 3*j*j
      valp, valn = (jj - j)//2, (jj+j)//2
      result[valp] = j
      result[valn] = j
      j += 1

    return result
```

**Performance**

```
n    Time (sec)
10   time elapsed: 0.00087
50   time elapsed: 0.00059
100  time elapsed: 0.00125
200  time elapsed: 0.10933
```

> Conclusion: This algorithm is orders of magnitude faster than the simple recurrence relationship

**Algorithm**

[Reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html)

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you for detail answer, comparisons, explanations. The Wolfram algorithm is just, wow, much faster than I thought it would be. Also after viewing your code I now better understand how the implementation of these algorithms looks like, which is important.

Comment: @kaktus_car--glad it was helpful.  The tricky part was relating n to j, which I did by just enumerating j values and using the formula to see what n values they mapped onto a maintaining that in a dictionary.

Comment: Very helpful, because I've never encountered this type of problem and I did not know how to approach it. I learned much today. Yeah, and it was clever.

Answer (score 1):

```
def partQ(n):

    result = []

    def rec(part, tgt, allowed):
        if tgt == 0:
            result.append(sorted(part))
        elif tgt > 0:
            for i in allowed:
                rec(part + [i], tgt - i, allowed - set(range(1, i + 1)))

    rec([], n, set(range(1, n)))

    return result
```

The work is done by the `rec` internal function, which takes:

- `part` - a list of parts whose sum is always equal to or less than the target `n`
- `tgt` - the remaining partial sum that needs to be added to the sum of `part` to get to `n`
- `allowed` - a set of number still allowed to be used in the full partitioning

When `tgt = 0` is passed, that meant the sum of `part` if `n`, and the `part` is added to the result list. If `tgt` is still positive, each of the allowed numbers is attempted as an extension of `part`, in a recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, the code works but it is not what I need. I want to get only the number of combinations, or regarding your answer `len(result)` without computing them (or if it is possible to compute them fast), so the answer for large n would be very quick. Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: @amital, You've got some small bugs.  you need to handle tgt == 1, and the initial call should have set(range(1, n+1))

Comment: @RobNeuhaus - Regarding the >1 issue - corrected the code (although I suspect it does not matter). Regarding the `range(1, n + 1)` suggestion, I think that would be incorrect, since it will include the trivial partition, which the output samples do not include.

Answer (score 1):

You can memoize the recurrences in equations 8, 9, and 10 in the mathematica article you linked for a quadratic in N runtime.

Comment: Good suggestion, I agree it is the best approach.